# Do self referencing entities need @OneToOne JPA annotations or not?

Tags: jpa, one-to-one, self-referencing-table

Imagine an Entity A has a non-mandatory one-to-one relationship with itself, say something like the diagram below.
[image: diagram]

Do I write `sourceTransaction` and `destinationTransaction` as: `public DepositAccountTransaction sourceTransaction; public DepositAccountTransaction destinationTransaction;` without any annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you always will need the annotation. If it is optional:

```
@OneToOne(optional = true)
private DepositAccountTransaction destinationTransaction;
```

I wouldn't declare any property as public btw. You may want to use projectlombok to generate getters and setters.